# A question about extending polynomial span to monomial basis

Tags: linear-algebra, chebyshev-polynomials, chebyshev-function, monomial-order

I have a final next week and our instructor gave us some examples with solutions but I could not understand some operations.

Inner product is
$$(p,q)=\int_{-1}^{1} p(t)q(t)dt$$

$W = Span\{1,t,t^2\}$ in solution it says extend this span to standard monomial basis $1,t^2,t^3,t^4$. In this basis, the matrix of the inner product is
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 2\over3 & 0 & 2\over5 \\
        0 & 2\over3 & 0 & 2\over5 & 0 \\
        2\over3 & 0 & 2\over5 & 0 & 2\over7 \\
        0 & 2\over5 & 0 & 2\over7 & 0 \\
        2\over5 & 0 & 2\over7 & 0 & 2\over9 \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I get this?

Thanks for answers.

Edit: Correction.

Comment: I believe there is more information not included in your question.  For example, the inner product and the interval in question is not stated but you do quote "cf (1)" so I presume there's an integral (with limits) not stated here but stated in your question (or previous notes?).

Comment: If I had to guess from the matrix you have, the inner product, with matrix elements $M_{ij}$, is defined by $M_{ij} = \int_{-1}^{1}a_i(t)a_j(t)dt$, where $a_i(t)$ are the basis elements. The matrix you write is then directly obtained by integrating the different basis elements.

Comment: You also need to state what $n$ is in the second part of your question.  Is it the degree of a Chebyshev polynomial or something else?

Comment: I edited the question sorry for missing information

Comment: Actually i got the second part but i still cant understand the first part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in comments above, you have the second part answered (if so, please add that to the answer above or edit out the second part so the Q&A stands as a self-contained "unit") so I've only answered the first part.

To obtain the matrix elements, use the inner product defined by the integral in the question.

$$
M_{ij} = \int_{-1}^{1}a_i(t) b_j(t)dt.
$$

For example, the element in the first row, third column
$$
M_{13} = (1,t^2) = \int_{-1}^{1}1 \dot t^2 dt = \left[ \frac{t^3}{3}\right]_{-1}^{1} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{-1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

The other elements can be obtained similarly, case by case.  Generally, however, you can calculate:

$$
M_{nm} = (t^n,t^m) = \int_{-1}{1} t^{n+m} dt = \left[\frac{t^{n+m+1}}{n+m+1}\right]^{1}_{-1} = \frac{1^{n+m+1}}{n+m+1} - \frac{(-1)^{n+m+1}}{n+m+1} \\ = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $m+n+1$ is even} \\
2\over{n+m+1}, & \text{if $n+m+1$ is odd}
\end{cases} 
$$

This gives all the matrix elements (labelled with $m=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ and  $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$) and agrees with the matrix you provide.